# How to display my search results in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have UIView that has two textfield,two labels ,UICollectionView, and one search bar.I want to add  searchdisplaycontroller and searchbar to my UIView.

i have linked my datasources and delegate to search.

```
searchBar=[UISearchBar new];
searchDisplayController=[[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate=self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource=self;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

My problem is the searchdisplaycontroller has results in **searchResultsTableView**  and can be easily populated with tableview delegates but i have UICollectionView.

How can i display my search results in collection view delegate methods?
My view looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to use a `UICollectionView` along with a `UISearchBar`, or `UITextField` with search capability. The `UISearchDisplayController` only supports table representation of data. Also, it is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: does **UISearchController** supports other representation of data than table?

Comment: i finally.did it with plain **UISearchBar** and reloading it with **[collectionview reloadData]**

Answer (score 0):

> With UISearchDisplayController, this would be simple: create a
>   UISearchBar and add it to a custom UICollectionView section header,
>   then initialize the UISearchDisplayController with the search bar

Have a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992762/2082569

Comment: The OP specifies the need to use a `UICollectionView`. `UISearchDisplayController`, apart from being deprecated in iOS 8, does not have a `UICollectionView`, but a `UITableView`.